# Does the death of Kilogram ($kg$) affect us in any means in our day to day life?

Tags: mass, conventions, si-units, metrology

Recently, the *sleek cylinder* of **platinum-iridium** metal has been **discarded** and the kilogram is set to be **redefined** along with *ampere* for electricity and *Kelvin* for temperature. Hereafter the [Kilogram is dead](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/11/16/science/kilogram-physics-measurement.html) and does it affect us in any means?

Comment: I would say no. It doesn't even affect the majority of physicists.

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147433/what-are-the-proposed-realizations-in-the-new-si-for-the-kilogram-ampere-kelvi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no

Slightly longer answer: One of the primary goals of the BIPM is to ensure continuity in all redefinitions of the SI. So the numerical value of Planck’s constant chosen to define the kilogram was chosen precisely to prevent any discontinuity. In other words, avoiding any “day to day life” impact is an intentional part of the redefinition.

Answer (score 2):

The international kilogram prototype was just redefined because it lost some of its mass during the course of years. So just it was redefined to its initial mass.
It does not have any significant impact on our daily life or on the previous calculations because the loss in mass was very small (approximately 0.000005 milligrams).