# After the redefinition of the units of fundamental physical quantities in 2019, will an uncertainty incur in the Universal constants values?

Tags: units, physical-constants, si-units

I am specifically interested in the following constants because being a student these are some of the most common constants that I face:

1. $R$ (universal gas constant)
2. Stefan constant
3. Permeability of free space
4. $G$ (universal gravitational constants)

Starting from 2019, scientists have redefined the units of fundamental quantities. The definition of kilogram, kelvin and ampere have been changed. In the new system, Planck's constant $h$, Boltzmann's Constant $k$, Avogadro's Number $N_A$, speed of light $c$, and charge on an electron $e$ are given constant fixed values. So the definition of kilogram, kelvin and ampere is given in terms of definition of **metre,sec,mole and these fundamental constants**. How will this affect the constant values that we have used since such a long time?
 I have mentioned just a few constants only to just get a brief idea about the effect of this redefinition.

Comment: Required reading on the new SI units: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/232182/50583

Comment: Could you please simplify the content and help me to get the highlights of your link which answers my question because I am not able to completely understand the link which you have forwarded.